# how to align right control in td html5

Tags: html, html-table

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="ID">
            </dx:ASPxButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

how to align "btnOk" to rigth side of td?

in html(not html5) is use `<td align="right">` but in html5 i don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  align attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

```
<div class="right" >

 <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="ID">
            </dx:ASPxButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: @user2955394: If u find the answer right, update it to be correct plz.

Comment: why is it not supported in html5?